# Type of Define expression in Scheme

Tags: types, scheme, racket

To put it simply: My question is whats is the type of a define expression in Scheme?

Take for example:

```
(define x 5)
```

or

```
(define x (lambda (n) (* n n)))
```

It's a bit confusing for me. Can anyone help?

Comment: What do you mean by its type? `define` does not have return value (and thus no return type) as it's not an expression.

Comment: define actually is an expression. Now, for your other question: what do I mean by type? Well, you could say that '5 has the type of Number', '#f has the type of Boolean', '(lambda (n) (* n n))' has the type of [Number -> Number]. My question is: what is the type of a define expression? I hope i made myself clear.

Comment: Not in Racket it's not. If you try to use it in an expression context, Racket will produce the error message "define: not allowed in an expression context".

Comment: Ofcourse it is. (define x 5) is an expression. I've never heard of the mentioned error, sounds pretty puzzling to me. Are you sure we're talking about the same thing?

Comment: No, it isn't. Not in Racket. Just try defining a variable whose value is the result of a define. Or calling a function with define as its argument (like `(display (define x 42))`). You'll get the error I cited.

Comment: In racket `(define x 5)` is a statement, not an expression, in the sense that evaluating it produces a value. It's like asking about the type of `if (x) { ... }` in Java. it's not that its type is `void` or something; it simply isn't meaningful to talk about it having a type at all.

Comment: What you did is assuming define returns a value, I did not state that anywhere. define, like many others, is an expression in Scheme/Racket. The point is, it may not return a value, and in that case It'd be something similiar to void.

Comment: @TheEmeritus If an expression returns `void`, I can still pass that as an argument to a function or store it in a variable. `(define foo bar)` does not return a void. It can not be used as an expression at all.

Comment: Expressions have types, statements do not. This is a matter of definition. There is no meaningful answer to the question of what type a statement has.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Racket [`define`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/define.html?q=define#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._define%29%29) is a special form and not an expression, so it doesn't have a value per-se, if you try to execute something like this you'll get an error:

```
(display (define x 42))
=>  define: not allowed in an expression context in: (define x 42)
```

If it were to have a value it'd be something akin to [`void`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/void.html), but that will be dependent on the particular implementation details of the interpreter (I believe I saw one interpreter return `#t` after a `define` was completed)

> The constant `#<void>` is returned by most forms and procedures that have a side-effect and no useful result

The [specification](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-14.html#node_sec_11.2) doesn't go into details on this point, either - reinforcing the statement that it's implementation-dependent.

Comment: `define` is not an expression in Racket. If you use it in an expression context, you get an error - not `#void`.

Comment: If you only write 'define', then it may not be an expression as you stated. But writing '(define x 5)' or anything else of that kind is an expression in 100%.

Comment: @TheEmeritus the error message is clear: a `define` can not be used where an expression is expected

Comment: @TheEmeritus, you are wrong.  Learn by reading any Scheme RnRS document.

Comment: See also: [Racket > Syntax Model # Expansion Context](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/syntax-model.html#(part._expand-context-model))