# What's the return value of `define` in Scheme?

Tags: lisp, scheme, racket, r5rs

I'm curious about the return value of `define` in Scheme. So I wrote the following lines in Racket

```
#lang r5rs
(display (define a 3))
```

And get the error

```
 define: not allowed in an expression context in: (define a 3)
```

I have 2 questions about this:

1. Does it mean that `define` has no return value?
2. According to R5RS, `define` is not an expression. It's a program structure. Is it true that only expressions have return values, and other forms don't?

Comment: This answer ( http://stackoverflow.com/a/15504315/1730344 ) says it is "implementation-dependent".

Comment: @jksLiu Thanks. I've searched but didn't notice that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Type of Define expression in Scheme](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15504117/type-of-define-expression-in-scheme)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

["If a tree falls in a forest and no one is around to hear it, does it make a sound?"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_a_tree_falls_in_a_forest)

It's not valid to use `define` in any context where a return value could meaningfully be obtained. So it's moot whether it has a return value or not; you'll never be able to observe it.

Answer (score 0):

In Scheme, `define` can only be used in [two places](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/):

1. At the top level, or
2. At the very beginning of a "body".

In neither of those places is a "return value" relevant.